# Regex: splitting text into words, spaces and commas: except single quotted abbreviations

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

I need to split Unicode text to array, keeping spacing and punctuation.Problem: I need to face abreviations like "That's" or "'till" as a single term.

What I came got far:

```
$String = "'till I got this help, I could not do by myself!";

$arr = preg_split("/(\s|\W)/u", $String, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE |PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
foreach ($arr as $word){
    echo "<span class=\"Term $word\">".$word."</span>";   
}
```

> - [0] => '
> - [1] => till
> - [2] =>
> - [3] => I
> - [4] =>
> - [5] => got
> - [6] =>
> - [7] => this
> - [8] =>
> - [9] => help
> - [10] => ,
> - [11] =>
> - [12] => I
> - [13] =>
> - [14] => could
> - [15] =>
> - [16] => not
> - [17] =>
> - [18] => do
> - [19] =>
> - [20] => by
> - [21] =>
> - [22] => myself
> - [23] => !
>
> )

Comment: Check for `\W\B`

Comment: `/(\s|[^\w'])/u`

Comment: @revo bingo! it saved my week. I need to find a good regex resource to learn it.

Comment: Except when quote is at the end `todays' task` back to the drawing board ..

Comment: To avoid the ambiguity, use this instead `/(\s|[^\w']|\B'\B)/u`

Comment: Thanks @sln, but if I am splitting a German text it is messing a bit, ignoring punctuation and displaying ' and ö as HTML entities. I need the complete text afterwards. Do you know how do I handle this?

$String="Das ist 'ne Text! Oder Röthig?";

Array
(
    [0] => Das
    [1] => ist
    [2] => 
    [3] => 
    [4] => 039
    [5] => ne
    [6] => Text
    [7] => 
    [8] => Oder
    [9] => R
    [10] => ouml
    [11] => thig
    [12] => 
)

Comment: I fear you did not include the Unicode option `//u` see here [/(\s|\[^\w'\]|\B'\B)/u](https://regex101.com/r/bSfq8N/1)

Comment: Many thanks for the effort. I think it is something on the rest of my code. In a clean file it works, but a word like "erklär'n" is being split as "erklär"," ' ","en". It was supposed to be a single word. Is there a way just to face ' as A-z? or just to avoid this?

Comment: You can't really workaround this, split should match the single word `erklär'n` since the regex does not match any character inside. See this https://regex101.com/r/bSfq8N/2. I'm leaving now, but post a link to an online php tester with the code that reproduces this problem. And put an `@` in front of my name in a comment as a reminder to me. I'll check it later or tomorrow...

Comment: @sln Thanks! http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1483adfb21c5eafed5e8a4b43b38b316b9d7977a

Comment: No problem. Use this `/(\s|\[[^\[\]]+\]|[^\w'‘]|\B['‘]\B)/u` http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/195f16584efb1d75be91f86160e231a950899ec1.

Comment: Some notes on that. When you add to the alternation list, you're adding to the delimiter list. Add the more complex items like multi-word items `\[[^\[\]]+\]` first (or before the other's) in the list. The more primitive items put last `[^\w'‘]|\B['‘]\B`. Note that on this one `[^\w'‘<add chars here>]|\B['‘<add the exact chars here as well>]\B` the classes are exclusionary in the first one and inclusionary in the second one. They work together so, modify them both .. i.e. add the same special chars to _both_ classes.

Comment: As a side note, if it were me, I'd grab multiple whitespace as a single delimiter `\s+` this avoids the voluminous slag, while still showing separation.

Comment: Many thanks for the effort! It worked like a charm. It just solved my doubt.